# How to get to Wulai Hot Spring in Taipei by public transport

Tags: taiwan, taipei, hot-springs

There is a hot spring place called [Wulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wulai_District) near Taipei city but how to get there by public transport?

Answer (score 4):

You can take 849 bus from multiple MRT train stations to Wulai.

1. [Taipei Main Station](https://goo.gl/maps/MNSi7oYuRTTAvXE49)
2. [MRT NTU Hospital Station](https://goo.gl/maps/9VqT3K7hwNezWoQq9)
3. [MRT Gongguan Station](https://goo.gl/maps/xxx4XtLrRbyGogNo8)
4. [MRT Xindian Station](https://goo.gl/maps/WWfCow1vicVFh5By6)

Price for adult (全票) is TWD 45 from the Taipei Main station to Wulai.

[image]

The bus leaves every 15 or 20 minutes (as of 2023 SEP). Below is the time table of the buses leaving Wulai.

[image]

After arriving Wulai, go up the road (there is a parking building on the left) and there is an information center, a police station, and a convenience store that has ATM. Some hotels do not take credit cards so better to have cash at hand.

[image]

Going up further and cross the first bridge, there is a shopping street where you see hotels with hot spring.

[image]

[image]

Pass through the shopping street and you will see the 2nd bridge. There are more hotels with hot spring. You can just take bath there without staying nights.

[image]

At the end of the 2nd bridge, there is a entrance to the log cart station (stairs). One way ticket to the waterfall is TWD 50 (as of 2020 SEP). The cable car is TWD 300.

[image]
[image]

There used to be a timber logging industry carrying timber by the log carts but they are now for tourist to take you up to the waterfall and cable car station.

[image]

Wulai (烏來) means hot spring in native indigenous tribe language. **烏** means **bird** and **來** means **arrive** and it has nothing with the hot spring but the phonic sound of
烏-來 is Wu-lai. The tribe is called Takasago but it was the name given during the Japanese occupation, hence not the genuine naming for them.

The [Wulai Waterfall Visitor Center is run by the tribe](http://wulai-shuucho.com/) people and offer traditional dances and local produces.

[image]

Unfortunately it is not well located. Not sure why indigenous tribe does not get a place with better recognition. It is on the road near the cable car station entrance stairs. Google Map does not show it either. I wish people will visit there and meet the tribe people.

[image]